# How to display the template based on the roomList data using ngTemplateOutlet in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***TS***

```
roomList = [{
 name: 'Room2'
}]
```

***HTML***
<

```
div class="Layout-body">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let dt of roomList; index as i" [ngTemplateOutlet]="Room1" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ data: dt, i: i }" >
        </ng-container>
    </div>
    
    <ng-template #Room1 let-data="data" let-i="index">
        {{data}}
      </ng-template>
    <ng-template #Room2 let-data="data" let-i="index">
      {{data}}
    </ng-template>
```

How to display room template based on the roomList name.

for example 'Room2' then in ngTemplateOutlet will display the template of Room2.

Comment: I don't think it is possible what you try here. Did you consider ngSwitchCase? https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `TemplateRef` and refer that in the html using `this`

```
import {
  Component,
  VERSION,
  ViewChild,
  TemplateRef
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  roomList = [{
      name: "Room2"
    },
    {
      name: "Room1"
    }
  ];

  @ViewChild("Room1") Room1: TemplateRef <any> ;
  @ViewChild("Room2") Room2: TemplateRef <any> ;
}
```

```html
<div class="Layout-body">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let dt of roomList; index as i" [ngTemplateOutlet]="this[dt.name]" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ data: dt, i: i }">
  </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #Room1 let-data="data" let-i="index">
  {{data.name}}
</ng-template>
<ng-template #Room2 let-data="data" let-i="index">
  {{data.name}}
</ng-template>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-syte8k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
<div class="Layout-body">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let dt of roomList; index as i" [ngTemplateOutlet]="([Room1, Room2])[i]" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ data: dt, i: i }" >
    </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #Room1 let-data="data" let-i="index">
    {{data | json}}
  </ng-template>
<ng-template #Room2 let-data="data" let-i="index">
  {{data | json}}
</ng-template>
```

Comment: cause you just defined one item ```roomList = [{name: 'Room1'}, {name: 'Room2'}] ```

Comment: for example it's only one item, then it should display the Room based on the name.

Comment: Not sure what are you expected but you can see at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tttv8y?file=src/app/input-overview-example.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tttv8y-6uuphd?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.ts

Comment: I see. So, from @brk solution it should work as your expected